# How to write a getter for a container of shared_ptrs which does not allow modification of data

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, shared-ptr

Let's say I have a private variable which is a vector of `shared_ptr`s to non-`const` objects.

Is it possible to write a getter method which only allows read access to the data pointed to by the shared pointers?

I want to be able to use range-based loops for elegance, so I want to avoid writing `const_iterators`.

My understanding is that const `shared_ptr<T>` makes the pointer itself `const`, not `T`. I tried to compile `shared_ptr<const T>`, but it doesn't compile if `T` itself is not declared `const` in the class.

In other words, how could I write something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class MyClass{

public:
    MyClass(int element1, int element2)
    {
        myVector_.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(element1));
        myVector_.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(element2));
    }

    // I want something like this, but doesn't compile
//  const vector<shared_ptr<const int>> readMyVector() const {return myVector_;}

    const vector<shared_ptr<int>> readMyVector() const {return myVector_;}

private:

    // Should NOT be <const int>, the class should be able to modify its elements
    vector<shared_ptr<int>> myVector_;
};

int main(){
    auto testobject = MyClass(1,2);
    for (auto my_protected_data : testobject.readMyVector()){
        cout<<(*my_protected_data)<<endl;
        (*my_protected_data) = 25;
        cout<<(*my_protected_data)<<endl; // Should not happen
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type to return is `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>>`, but you'll have to make that vector by hand. `std::shared_ptr<T>` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<const T>`, but the problem is that `std::vector<T>` isn't implicitly convertible to `std::vector<U>` simply because `T` is convertible to `U`.

The easiest way is to construct a vector from your internal vector's `begin` and `end` iterators.

```
vector<shared_ptr<const int>> readMyVector() const 
{
    return{ myVector_.begin(), myVector_.end() };
}
```

Note that adding `const` to the return type of a function that returns by value is rarely useful.

You should also ask yourself rather it's worth it to copy all of those `std::shared_ptr`. You may want to consider simply returning a vector of `int`.

Comment: "*You may want to consider simply returning a vector of int*" - agreed. If you don't want people touching the original data, don't give direct access to it in the first place.

Comment: In the end this is what I did, but put weak_ptrs in the vector instead. I used ints for the example, in reality I have some very large objects that I shouldn't really be copying :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your getter to return vector of shared pointers to const data, there is only one way, to return copy of shared pointers to const data.

```
const vector<shared_ptr<const int>> readMyVector() const 
{
   vector<shared_ptr<const int>> cdata(myVector_.begin(), myVector_.end());
   return cdata;
}
```